# Override TYPO3 templates

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I have a TYPO3 website that is built on a sitepackage that extends bootstrap_package. I need to add more templates and design changes to the sitepackage, so I created a new extension. When I want to override the templates from sitepackage with the templates from my new extension, they all get overridden, and I get errors on the pages that used templates from the sitepackage.
Is there a way to load all templates, from the initial bootstrap_package, my sitepackage, and the new extension?

This is from the constants.txt of the sitepackage (example_theme), where it extends bootstrap_package:
[constants.txt of the sitepackage example_theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDF0H.png) ,
[image: constants.txt of the sitepackage example_theme]

and this is how I am trying to override it with my new extension: [constants.typoscript of my new extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7LZ3.png)
[image: constants.typoscript of my new extension]
and [setup.txt of the sitepackage example_theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ProTn.png)
[image: setup.txt of the sitepackage example_theme]

If I do this, then in the backend I can see that example_theme is not loaded:
[backend setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VygsM.png)
[image: backend setup]

The pages that used templates from the sitepackage example_theme give me this error:
[error on pages that use templates from example_theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk94T.png)
[image: error on pages that use templates from example_theme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have the wrong loading order of the extensions, or there is an extension not loaded.

Especially if you use only constants to define the paths you will miss a definition as only one constant (per path) is inserted.

In your case you should not use constants in your extension `new_extension` but set the value `2` in the setup immediately.

```
page {
  10 {
    TemplateRootPaths.2 = EXT:new_extension\Resources\Private\Templates\Page\
    PartialRootPaths.2 = EXT:new_extension\Resources\Private\Partials\Page\
    LayoutRootPaths.2 = EXT:new_extension\Resources\Private\Layouts\Page\
  }
}
```

in this way you should end up with 3 values for each path.
(example just for templates:)

```
:
[templateRootPaths]
   [0] = EXT:bootstrap_package\Resources\Private\Templates\Page\
   [1] = EXT:example_theme\Resources\Private\Templates\Page\
   [2] = EXT:new_extension\Resources\Private\Templates\Page\
```

Comment: Thank you! I added that in the setup of my new extension and it worked!